# Jquery - siblings('label').show() doesnt work in IE7 for checkbox click but works for Dropdown change

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer-7

I have a code snippet in which on click of checckbox I am hiding and showing the field and its label.

**IN IE7**

Though the hide() using siblings works fine, 
but on clicking again the checkbox, siblings(label).show() doesn't work

**HTML CODE**

> **UPDATE**

```
    <div class="rightcolumn" id="otherlabeldiv">
                    <p class="clearboth">
                      <label for="othermakemodel"> Other Make & Model</label>
                      <input type="checkbox" name="othermakemodel" id="othermakemodel" value="1" class="chk"  />
                    </p>
                  </div>
<div class="rightcolumn" id="otherdiv" style="display:none;">
    <p class="clearboth">
                      <label for="cemake">* Make</label>
                      <select name="cemake" id="cemake" class="required">
                        <option value="Please Select">--Please Select--</option>
                        <option value="Other">Other</option>
                      </select>
                    </p>
                    <p class="clearboth">
                      <label for="cemodel">* Model</label>
                      <select name="cemodel" id="cemodel" class="required">
                        <option value="">--Please Select--</option>
                        <!-- <option value="Other">Other</option>-->
                      </select>
                    </p>
</div>
```

**JQUERY USED**

```
 function setUpAjaxCalls(){

        $('#cemake').live('change', function() {
        var val = $('#cemake :selected').text();
        val = val.replace("(",'&#040;');
        val = val.replace(")",'&#041;');
        val = encodeURIComponent(val);

        if (val == 'Other'){
        //alert(val);
                        $('#othermakemodel').hide();
                        $('#othermakemodel').siblings('label').hide();
                        $('#other_hide').val('1');
                        $('#otherdiv').show();
                        $('#cemodel').hide();
                        $('#cemodel').siblings('label').hide();
        }else{
            $('#other_hide').val('');
            $('#othermakemodel').show();
            $('#othermakemodel').siblings('label').show();
            $('#otherdiv').hide();
            $('#cemodel').show();
            $('#cemodel').siblings('label').show();
        }

    });
    }

$(document).ready(function(){
setUpAjaxCalls();
    $("#othermakemodel").click(function() {
            if($('#othermakemodel').is(':checked')){
             $('#cemake').hide();

                $('#cemake').siblings('label').hide();



               $('#cemodel').hide();

               $('#cemodel').siblings('label').hide();
            }else{
            $('#cemake').show();// THIS WORKs
                $('#cemake').siblings('label').show(); // THIS DOESNT WORK
            $('#cemodel').show();// THIS WORKs
                $('#cemodel').siblings('label').show();// THIS DOESNT WORK  
            }
    }); 
});
```

Please help me up for this issue.

ABOVE IS THE UPDATED CODE in which you can see a change in value of "cemake" to "Other" hodes/show the other make/model text box with the same sibling concept which is not working for checkbox...

Comment: Try `change` instead of `click`.

Comment: Already Tried it.. It also doesnt work, Infact using change had worst effects

Comment: Didn't understood the "Sibling + selector does't work in IE7 when using jQuery" post at all. how is that related to mine question

Comment: May Be I am acting as "Urm", but I saw the bug and it is talking about the inner hierarchy while in mine code it is refering to the id of input and wants to hide/show the associated label.....

Comment: @Padyster It doesn't matter what he's doing with it, what matters is the bug is jQuery itself and it affects both of you. Follow the solution by using the appropriate next()/find() selectors instead of what you're using and your code will work.

Comment: Thanks @Zenith for constant instructions.... I am thinking for subsitute script to function same.

Comment: @Padyster In your case, just replace both of the `siblings('label') `with `prev('label')`

Comment: @Zenith Its not working with prev as well even i tried with sinple $('#id').show(); but it didnt work

Comment: yes my hide code works but my show code doesnt work thats the point that how can a function partially behave?

Comment: @Padyster I meant, in your else statement, your comments next to $('#cemake').show(); says it works..

Comment: @Zenith It doesn't work with IE 7

Comment: @Padyster Change show() and hide() with css('display','block') and css('display', 'none') etc.

Comment: @Zenith :'( Negative......

Comment: @Zenith I am updating thee code in question... please go through it...

Comment: What jQuery version are you using?

Comment: I believe there is some other code you have not mentioned here, which is causing problem to you.. please paste the complete jquery code herein